# Python - adding number to a value returned by a function

Tags: python, pandas

Following code correctly displays number 31:

```
str = 15
print(str+16)
```

Following code also correctly prints lengths of each column in a pandas' dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Test\File1.csv', low_memory=False)

for col in df:
   print(col, '->', df[col].str.len().max())
```

But I want to add 10 (in the `print(...)` method). But, when I add `10` to the last line of the above code, it ignores 10 and still displays only the actual length of each column.

**Question**: How can we make the last line of the code above to display `length of each column + 10`?

For example, if lengths of column1, column2,....column150 are as follows: 5, 11, ....,45 I would like these to be displayed as: 15,21,...55:

```
for col in df:
   print(col, '->', df[col].str.len().max()+10)
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['abra','njcasjdcn'],columns = ["c1"])
df["c2"] = df["c1"]*2
for col in df:
    print(col, '->', df[col].str.len().max()+10)
```

it outputs the correct result. The only things which could be different in your code are your pandas version, IDE, python version or DataFrame.